# deploying birt viewer in tomcat with excel datasource

Tags: eclipse, excel, tomcat, birt, viewer

im trying to run a predifined report in tomcat , i followed the instructions and successfully installed and tested birt viewer .
i use excel sheets as datasource and the reports works fine on eclipse , but when im trying to run them on tomcat , the reports aren't generated , here's the error message :

org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information. Report parameter "hours" does not exist.

Im using birt 3.7 , eclipse juno, tomcat 7.0

thank you .

Comment: I have noticed occasionally reports will run in BIRT preview, but not when using Apache Tomcat to view them.  I just problem solve the issue like I would any error, clean up the code, and get it working.  Actually I almost never test in preview for Apache Tomcat reporting, I have a test server set up with Apache and BIRT, and I test the reports as I write them in Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Try increasing the log4j log level for BIRT. Sometimes this gives a more descriptive error message.

Comment: which excel connection driver did  u used?

Answer (score 0):

check if u have added the driver u used for connecting excel to the birts runtime **'lib'** folder.